# Is the iPhone keyboard button class public?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

An app I'm developing needs a limited set of keyboard buttons in a custom view and I want the buttons to be identical to the standard iphone keyboard buttons, but this button style doesn't seem to be available in UIButton. Am I missing something?